# How to pass arguments inside select and test function?

Tags: bash, jq

I've this JSON data, extracted from qbittorrent:

```
[
  {
    "hash": "333333333333333333333333333",
    "name": "testtosearchcaseinsensitive",
    "magnet_uri": "magnet:somedata",
    "size": 1243989552,
    "progress": 1.0,
    "dlspeed": 0,
    "upspeed": 0,
    "priority": 0,
    "num_seeds": 0,
    "num_complete": 2,
    "num_leechs": 0,
    "num_incomplete": 32,
    "ratio": 0.0,
    "eta": "1.01:11:52",
    "state": "stalledUP",
    "seq_dl": false,
    "f_l_piece_prio": false,
    "category": "category",
    "tags": "",
    "super_seeding": false,
    "force_start": false,
    "save_path": "/data/path/",
    "added_on": 1567358333,
    "completion_on": 1567366287,
    "tracker": "somedata",
    "dl_limit": null,
    "up_limit": null,
    "downloaded": 1244073666,
    "uploaded": 0,
    "downloaded_session": 0,
    "uploaded_session": 0,
    "amount_left": 0,
    "completed": 1243989552,
    "ratio_limit": 1.0,
    "seen_complete": 1567408837,
    "last_activity": 1567366979,
    "time_active": "1.01:00:41",
    "auto_tmm": true,
    "total_size": 1243989552,
    "max_ratio": 1,
    "max_seeding_time": 2880,
    "seeding_time_limit": 2880
  },
  {
    "hash": "44444444444444",
    "name": "dontmatch",
    "magnet_uri": "magnet:somedata",
    "size": 2996838603,
    "progress": 1.0,
    "dlspeed": 0,
    "upspeed": 0,
    "priority": 0,
    "num_seeds": 0,
    "num_complete": 12,
    "num_leechs": 0,
    "num_incomplete": 0,
    "ratio": 0.06452786606740063,
    "eta": "100.00:00:00",
    "state": "stalledUP",
    "seq_dl": false,
    "f_l_piece_prio": false,
    "category": "category",
    "tags": "",
    "super_seeding": false,
    "force_start": false,
    "save_path": "/data/path/",
    "added_on": 1566420155,
    "completion_on": 1566424710,
    "tracker": "some data",
    "dl_limit": null,
    "up_limit": null,
    "downloaded": 0,
    "uploaded": 193379600,
    "downloaded_session": 0,
    "uploaded_session": 0,
    "amount_left": 0,
    "completed": 2996838603,
    "ratio_limit": -2.0,
    "seen_complete": 4294967295,
    "last_activity": 1566811636,
    "time_active": "10.23:07:42",
    "auto_tmm": true,
    "total_size": 2996838603,
    "max_ratio": -1,
    "max_seeding_time": -1,
    "seeding_time_limit": -2
  }
]
```

So I want to match all data where the name have some text, so, in Bash I write this but I can't make it work.

Some declaration to start, actually I pass data via arguments, so I use `$1`:

```
TXTIWANT="test"
MYJSONDATA= Here I put my JSON data
```

Then this `jq` equation that doesn't work for me is this:

```
RESULTS=$(echo "$MYJSONDATA" | jq --raw-output --arg TOSEARCH "$TXTIWANT" '.[] | select(.name|test("$TOSEARCH.";"i")) .name')
```

But I always got an error or all data, I think because `$TOSEARCH` is not expanded.

Maybe there's a better way to search a string inside a value?

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax for variable (or filter) interpolation with `jq` looks like this:

```
"foo \(filter_or_var) bar"
```

In your case:

```
jq --raw-output --arg TOSEARCH "$TXTIWANT" '.[]select(.name|test("\($TOSEARCH).";"i")) .name')
```

---

side-note: [By convention, environment variables (PAGER, EDITOR, ...) and internal shell variables (SHELL, BASH_VERSION, ...) are capitalized. All other variable names should be lower case.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/171318)

Comment: Thanks, I also tried with .[var] but nothing. This's like an escape, because this's a regex pattern? Also thanks for the side-note.

Comment: np. The `\()` syntax is not a regex syntax. It's plain jq syntax. I've actually never tried how well that plays with the regular expression syntax. The `()` are potentially problematic. Good luck :P

Comment: ps: if you run into problems, keep in mind that you could also use concatenation: `"foo " + $tosearch + " bar"`

Comment: @hek2mgl - The parens are not problematic.  Interpolation takes place first.

Comment: Hi, actually I've some problem with ( and or [, I've to better check the output and I've to try the @peak solution

Comment: jesus man ive spent legit 4 hours trying to sort this out and NOWHERE ELSE described how \\($ARG) was the syntax to use in a regex test. @JormanFranzini you need to accept this answer!

Answer (score 1):

If (as suggested by the name TXTIWANT and by the example, as well as by the wording of the question) the value of "$TXTIWANT" is supposed to be literal text, then using `test` is problematic, as `test` will search for a regular expression.

Since it is not clear from the question why you are adding a period to TOSEARCH, in the remainder of this first section, I will ignore whatever requirement you have in mind regarding that.

So if you simply want to find the `.name` values that contain $TXTIWANT literally (ignoring case), then you could convert both `.name` and the value of $TXTIWANT to the same case, and then check for containment.

In jq, ignoring the mysterious ".", this could be done like so:

```
jq --raw-output --arg TOSEARCH "$TXTIWANT" '
  ($TOSEARCH|ascii_upcase) as $up
  | .[]
  | .name
  | select(ascii_upcase|index($up))'
```

### Search for non-terminal occurrence of $TXTIWANT ignoring case

If the "." signifies there must be an additional character after $TXTIWANT, then you could just add another `select` as follows:

```
  ($TOSEARCH|length) as $len
  | ($TOSEARCH|ascii_upcase) as $up
  | .[]
  | .name
  | (ascii_upcase|index($up)) as $ix
  | select($ix)
  | select($ix + $len < length)
```

Comment: Hi @peak, thanks for your suggestion, I've to better check and try your solution. Yes is text but is possible to have ( or [ or dot, I use . to include all over the text. If help maybe is better to clean the input and output text without special char? What do you think?

Comment: what about this: echo "$LISTS" | jq --raw-output --arg TOSEARCH "$TXTIWANT" '.[] | select(.name == "\($TOSEARCH)") | .hash' I just noticed that I already have all json data extracted, so I have the exact name inside the $LISTS